# In Bash how to read the properties of a file?

Tags: bash

I am very new to bash scripting.

I need to make a bash script which finally copies files from one directory to another directory.

But target directory for all the files does not have be the same for all the files in the source directory. If the target directory does not exists then it must be created. The name of the new directory depends on the creation date of the concerning file. The format of the directory name is YYYY_MM_DD.

Therefor I must read the properties of the file, and then check if the target directory exists. If not, then the create the directory and copy the file. If it exists then copy the file.
How can I read the properties of a file? How can I create a new directory in format YYYY_MM_DD? How can I check if the directory already exists?

To know the target directory, the script needs to read the properties of every file in the source directory via a loop. How can I loop through the files in a directory?

Have I made myself clear? If not, ask me for more information.

Thank you.

Carlos Wiesemann

Comment: But most of the times the creation time of a file is not known. To find out the creation time you can use stat ( Like this : stat --format "%W" <filename> )

Comment: All of your questions have answers if you look for them. Have you tried anything yourself or do you just want someone to write the script for you?

Comment: Like I said, I am new with bash scripting. I want to learn it. And of course I want to write the script by my self.
But sometimes some one wants/needs some help. And I beleive that this website is the place to be for such questions.
I am sorry if I have offended you with my questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read the last modification date file in a directory via a loop

```
ls | stat --format "%n - %y" *
```

or if you don't like the ls command, as Cyrus sugested, remove it ;-)

```
stat --format "%n - %y" *
```

Comment: I suggest to remove `ls |`.